# How to save and restore SwiftData database

Tags: swift, swift-data

I would like to make a backup all the SwiftData database of my iOS application so I can restore it later. I would like to have this available as one file/folder in the File section available when I connect my iPhone to my mac.

Any idea on how to do that ?